# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[imageIndex].img_testeo')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, fetch

I've been having this error when pressing a button. I have several functions in my code. I will attach them together with the code. Hope you understand it

Here's the error

```
      data.length > 0 &&
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Image source={{ uri: `data:image/jpg;base64,${data[imageIndex].img_testeo}` }}
            style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
        </View>
```

The button (which has 2 functions on it)

```
<MyButton
                titulo='Siguiente imagen'
                onPress={() => siguienteImagen(numeroElegido)} /> : //This is one function
              <MyButton
                titulo='Finalizar'
                onPress={() => navigateTo('Inicio')} /> //This one another
```

Function 1

```
 const [numeroElegido, setNumeroElegido] = useState(null)

  function navigateTo(routeName){  //Function 1 
    siguienteImagen(numeroElegido)
    navigation.navigate(routeName)
  }
```

Function 2:

```
function siguienteImagen(num_usuario) {
    enviarDatos(num_usuario)
    if (imageIndex !== data.length) {
      setImageIndex(imageIndex + 1)
      setNumeroElegido(null)
      console.log(data.length, "length")
      console.log(imageIndex, "imageIndex")
   
    }
  }
```

Function 3:

```
 function enviarDatos(num_usuario) {

    console.log("index:", imageIndex+1);

    fetch(`${varurl}/api/eval-test?usuario=1&imagen_id=${imageIndex+1}&num_ing=${num_usuario}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({})
    }).then((response) =>
      response.json()
    ).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your condition in function 2 `if (imageIndex !== data.length)` will always be true unless the imageIndex is out of bound. You should use `data.length-1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are using typescript and **data[imageIndex].img_testeo** here data could be undefined so typescript is giving error

for simple solution you chan use `data[imageIndex]?.img_testeo`

and another solution is describe the type of your data where you have defined it.
example : `interface ImageData { img_testeo: string; }`

`const [data, setData] = useState<ImageData>();`